# Transpose table add column

Tags: python, pandas

Good evening everyone.

I'm new to pandas and I'm having trouble creating a DataFrame.

I have a table that contains Deal_id, Stage_id and Created_at, this table stores the movements (Created_at) of my deals confrome goes through Stage_id:

[image]

I need to transpose this table so that it looks like this:

[image]

Applying distinct to Deal_id and storing your moves in specific columns (Deal_stage_id)

Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.pivot(index='deal_id',columns='stage_id',values='Created_at')
```